# Mysql sessions selecting ID i need Username

Tags: php, session

I have a login script and a UCP that uses ID's as user authentication(verification)...well basically it uses ID's to log the person in the right account. So what I need is to use the persons name not his ID.

Well here's what I've got in my Mysql:

table(serverplayers)

```
User - Users name that he registered In Game(This UCP and system is for a game)
ID - given by the server when registering(everyones are different)
```

And the UCP is written like this everywhere:
login.php =

```
if ($_SESSION['user'] > 0)
```

but that's the problem. It basically checks if the user's ID is bigger than zero that means hes logged in. If it's 0 he's logged out.
And that's everywhere.

```
if ($_SESSION['user'] == 0)
```

the web page shows him logged out content. I need the system to log in the user by his username not his ID. Is there anyway to do that without rewriting the whole script?

I hope I got this question right, but please ask if somethings wrong.

So okay heres my login.php

```
<?php
if ($_SESSION['narys'] != '') header('Location: index.html');
if (isset($_POST['User']))
{
$result = mysql_query('SELECT User, Password FROM serverplayers WHERE User=\''. $_POST['User'] .'\' LIMIT 1');
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if ($row['Password'] == $_POST['Slaptazodis']) {
$_SESSION['narys'] = $row['User'];
header('Location: index.html');
}
else echo '<center>
<b>Prisijungimas</b><br>
<br>
<br>Neteisingas slapyvardis arba slaptažodis<br>
<br>


<form method="post" action="login.html">
<input type="text" name="User" id="username" placeholder="Vartotojo vardas"><br>
<input type="password" name="Slaptazodis" id="slaptazodis" placeholder="Slaptažodis">
<<input type="submit" name="login" value="" id="jungtisvvp" >
</form>
<br>
... dar neturite sąskaitos? - <a href="register.html">Užsiregistruokite!</a></center>';
    if ($_SESSION['narys'] != '') exit; 
}
else
{
echo '
<form method="post" action="login.html">
<input type="text" name="User" id="username" placeholder="Vartotojo vardas"><br>
<input type="password" id="slaptazodis" placeholder="Slaptažodis">
<input type="submit" value="" id="jungtisvvp">
</form>

';
}
?>
```

And heres my header.php that selects user data:

```
if ($_SESSION['narys'] != ''){
$result = mysql_query('SELECT vModel, vOwner, Vip, VipDaysLeft, MoneyInBank, HaveBankAccount, Warns, TelphoneNumber, TelPhoneContract, Online, Job, HaveCredits, User, AdminLevel, AdminDaysLeft, PlayerX, PlayerY, PlayerZ, Experience, Money, Gender, Skin, Online, Health, Armour, Password, HaveCredits FROM serverplayers WHERE User='.$_SESSION['narys']);
$ro = mysql_fetch_array($result);
}
```

And this is basically how I show user data in webpage:

```
<li>Life: <div class="red-box">' .$ro['Health']. '</div></li>
```

Comment: Why can't you login by username, but set the session variable to the ID? If you also want a session variable with the username, use a different variable.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I'm trying to do.I'm tryng to get rid of the ID and only use the username as in place of the ID.But the problem as I said is how can i change the > 0 and == 0 to the username.The username is "varchar" and it's not numeric.So... i'm kind of a noob and trying to learn.And i checked google for session tutorials, but those are so complicated and I know that it's really basic stuff.So just to be basic I'm looking for an answer here to really get what's up.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the session variable to contain the name instead of ID, use:

```
if ($_SESSION['username'] == '') {
    // Not logged in
}

if ($_SESSION['username'] != '') {
    // Logged in
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but now I'm getting nothing.I changed `> 0` and `== 0` to your suggested `== ''` and `!= ''` but now it doesnt do anything. It doesn't show anything that's related to the user, but loggs in and loggs out . I don't know if im missing something or else...

Comment: You need to change everything else in your application to look up by username instead of by ID.

Comment: But as I see the `> 0` and `== 0` is the only thing how the script determines the user.So yeah it loggs me in but it doesnt show data from the user rows.Like healt, money etc.
Does it mean that something else is causing problems?

Comment: You said you're changing your scripts to use the user NAME instead of the ID. So it's no zero or non-zero any more.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't just set two session variables: one variable for the name, another for the ID. Then use whichever you need in other scripts.

Comment: Well the main reason is why I wanna' do this is because a player has a  vehicle that is stored in another table and is only connected to the player by his name.And if the player connects by the ID notthe username to the UCP, I cant get his vehicle to show in his UCP.I read about mysql joints but that's to complicated.I'm going to try your last suggestion

Comment: I know this is going to sound harsh, but if mysql joins are too complicated, find another line of work. They are a basic technique, and you won't get very far in database applications if you don't learn them right away.